# Help adding a CSR in iPhone Portal

Tags: iphone

I am new to the iPhone.  Following the instructions on the Apple website:

```
After creating a CSR, log in to the iPhone Provisioning Portal and navigate to ‘Certificates’ > ‘Development’ and click ‘Add Certificate’.
Click the ‘Choose file’ button, select your CSR and click ‘Submit’. If the Key Size was not set to 2048 bits during the CSR creation process, the Portal will reject the CSR.
Upon submission, Team Admins will be notified via email of the certificate request.
Once your CSR is approved or rejected by a Team Admin, you will be notified via email of the change in your certificate status.
```

I get stuck on the step about "Add Certificate."  I do not have that option on my screen.  My screen shows current development certificates, but it doesn't let me add a new one.  I did this like a yr ago and it has the last Certificate and says download or revoke, but I cannot add a new CSR.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The "How To' tab on the Certificates page is pretty helpful.

In addition, the main page of the provisioning portal has an assistant flow (look for a "Launch Assistant" button midway down the page) that takes you through all the steps of adding a new certificate.